# Accelerate to X velocity in Y seconds

Tags: c++, game-physics

How can I get something to go from X to Xgoal velocity in Y seconds?
The `goalVelocity` is set to (100, 100) and it does approach it but it takes way too long to get there.

I can multiply `frameDelta` by some number like 20 or 100 but I want to find out what to multiply `frameDelta` by to get it to reach `goalVelocity` in some number of seconds.

velocity, goalVelocity and origin are all `Vec2f` and frameDelta is a `float`

Right now I have this code:

```
velocity = approach(goalVelocity, velocity, frameDelta);
origin = origin + velocity * frameDelta;
```

The code for approach is:

```
inline float approach(float flGoal, float flCurrent, float dt)
{
    float flDifference = flGoal - flCurrent;

    if (flDifference > dt)
        return flCurrent + dt;
    if (flDifference < -dt)
        return flCurrent - dt;

    return flGoal;
}

inline Vec2f approach(Vec2f flGoal, Vec2f flCurrent, float dt)
{
    return Vec2f(approach(flGoal.x, flCurrent.x, dt), approach(flGoal.y, flCurrent.y, dt));
}
```

Comment: Do you know why you're using `inline`?

Comment: I got this code online, I'm assuming it's just because it's such a simple function.

Comment: You say `accelerate to X velocity in Y seconds`. I see you passing `X` to `approach` (in the form of `flGoal`), but I don't see you passing `Y`.

Comment: Right now I'm only passing frameDelta (which is dt in approach) because I don't know what I should be passing to do it in Y seconds

Comment: The time remaining to achieve the goal, of course.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how long it will be moving for since it's moving while a key is pressed

Comment: You've got to learn some vocabulary and basic physics first. I think you don't understand the words `velocity` or `origin`, because your use of the words doesn't match to the calculations you are making. An `origin` is fixed, but you are moving it. The term `frameDelta` is either delta velocity, or delta time, but not both. You are using at delta velocity in the first line, and delta time in the second. I think you should ask what problem you are trying to solve, ie accelerating a space ship with a key press?

Comment: You should probably pick up a highschool-level book on physics.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your Question, but acceleration is just speed difference divided by time, so just multiply `dt` with X/Y.

Answer (score 0):

A basic physics engine should look something like

```
   Vec2f position, velocity, acceleration;

   while (true)
   {
     acceleration = button ? thrust : 0;
     velocity += acceleration * timeDelta;
     position += velocity * timeDelta
     redraw space ship at position;
     sleep (timeDelta);
   }
```

if you want to go from 0 to X velocity in Y seconds, then `thrust = X/Y`.